# How do you read/write and combine the output of multiple .text files and create a single .txt file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, outputstream

In my program I'm trying to print my output to a file but the file is empty. The program reads text files in a directory. I get the desired output to the console but not in the output.text file. Not sure what is missing in the program. thanks in advance for the help.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CacheData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String target_dir = "C:\\Files";
        String output = "C:\\Files\\output.txt";
        File dir = new File(target_dir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (File textfiles : files) {
            if (textfiles.isFile() && textfiles.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;

                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textfiles));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);


                    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(output);
                    outputStream.println();
                    outputStream.close();
                    }

                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you intending to print what is in `line`? If so, pass `line` to `outputStream.println()`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're wanting to combine the contents of multiple files (text files in your case) into a single file.

Here's an IMO simpler solution.  Simpler in that you don't have to worry about safely opening and closing the files yourself as you read or write.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String targetDir = "Path to your directory of input files";
    String outputFile = "Path to your output file";

    File dir = new File(targetDir);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        // Only get files that end with .txt
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
        }
    });

    // Read all file lines into a List
    List<String> inputFileLines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File file : files) {
        inputFileLines.addAll(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())));
    }

    // Write the List to the console
    for (String line : inputFileLines) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    // Write the List to a single file
    Files.write(Paths.get(outputFile), inputFileLines, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(output);

                    //you are not printing anything to output file.
                    outputStream.println();

                    //Change it to
                    outputStream.println(line);
                    outputStream.close();
```

Comment: When I made the change using this suggestion the output file only contained 1 word. The text files I'm reading contain thousands of words. I'm able to generate the output to the console but its not writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications to your code to write to your file. Please see the inline-comments for further informations.

```
import java.io.*;

public class CacheData {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String target_dir = "C:\\Files";
    String output = "C:\\Files\\output.txt";
    File dir = new File(target_dir);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();

    for (File textfiles : files) {
        if (textfiles.isFile() && textfiles.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            BufferedReader inputStream = null;

            try {
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textfiles));
                String line;
                //open the Printwriter before your loop
                PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(output);
                while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);


                //Write Content not just linebreaks
                outputStream.println(line);

                }
                //close the outputstream after the loop
                outputStream.close();
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

To write the content of every txt-File in your file, move the Printwriter before the for-loop and close the printwriter after the for-loop and not just the while-loop.

Comment: I made the changes you noted but my output file is still empty.

Comment: The text files I'm reading contain thousands of words. I'm able to generate the output to the console but its not writing to the file.

Comment: just before you close the outputStream call flush() on the outputStream.

Comment: after calling flush() on the outputStream my output.txt file is still blank.